# Alternative parameterizations of the circle

Tags: computational-geometry, numerical-algorithms, algebra

When solving numerical problems with circles, one often has to sample these at numerous points, not necessarily in a uniform way. Evaluating the $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ values can represent a significant fraction of the cost, as they are transcendental functions.

We can get rid of these functions by rational substitutions, such as that of Weierstrass,

$$\cos\theta=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\\\sin\theta=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}.$$

This is better, though a division can also be costly, and covering the whole circle takes values in a wide range.

Another non-transcendental attempt could be

$$\cos\theta=u,\\\sin\theta=\pm\sqrt{1-u^2}$$ though this takes a square root, a sign decision and is not differentiable at $|u|=1$.

Are you aware of other parameterizations that allow to smoothly cover a full circle, with a low computational cost ? (Note that I am not after approximations nor incremental computations.)

Comment: Can you give an example of a problem where you need the parametrization? Since you are "solving numerical problems" and want to "sample these at numerous points", I'm confused why you need to "**smoothly** cover a full circle" and why you are "not after approximations". If approximations were allowed (which I believe is reasonable for numerical methods), I would consider generating few hundreds (or more, depending on required precision) points on the circle uniformly, and then approximating the points between them.

Comment: One idea to consider is to use rotation matrices. Let $M_\phi$ be a matrix rotating a point by angle $\phi$. If you generated some points with angles in $(0, \phi)$, you can multiply them by $M_\phi$ to get points with angles $(0, 2 \phi)$. Now, you multiply these points by $M_{2 \phi}$, and get points with angles in $(0, 4 \phi)$, etc. For $n$ uniformly distributed points, you'll need to compute $O(\log n)$ matrices. Each point is then computed by single matrix multiplication. [I've no idea if this approach will lead to any precision issues in your applications.]

Comment: @Dmitry: I have to solve ODE's on circles, where the independent variable is not the angle.

Comment: @Dmitry: the angles are not uniform. If they were, I would gladly use the "versine" method for iterated rotations.